# Object rotating while travelling along a curve path

Tags: three.js

I am creating a flight animation, I have objects (airplanes) moving along a curve path. My problem is some of my objects are rotating while travelling along the curve path.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9gFT.jpg)

```
function createPlane(image) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 5),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('textures/planes/' + image), side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true })
    );
}

// this is how we get the line.vertices
// var curve = new THREE.Curve();
// line.vertices = curve.getPoints(50);

function animatePlane(plane, line, key) {

    if (key > 1) {
        key = 1;
    } else {
        key = Math.round(key * 100) / 100;
    }

    var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(line.vertices), up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), axis = new THREE.Vector3();
    var angle, duration = 300, position = curve.getPointAt(key), tangent = curve.getTangentAt(key).normalize();

    // rotation
    axis.crossVectors(up, tangent).normalize();
    angle = Math.acos(up.dot(tangent));

    plane.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);

    // position
    new TWEEN.Tween(plane.position)
        .to({ x: position.x, y: position.y, z: position.z }, duration)   
        .onUpdate(function() {
            plane.position.set(this.x, this.y, this.z);
        })
        .onComplete(function() {

            if (key < 1) {
                key += 0.02;
            } else {
                key = 0;
            }

            animatePlane(plane, line, key);
        })
        .start();
}

// lines
var point = latLongToVector3(14.512274, 121.016508, radius, 0), // Philippines
    line1 = createCurveLine(createSphereArc(point, latLongToVector3(2.745364, 101.707079, radius, 0), 0.3), green, 'MALAYSIA');

animatePlane(createPlane('airplane.png'), line1, 0);
```

The above code is how I create and what moves my objects along the curve path.

Note that curve paths were dynamically created, from the screenshot above it is from Philippines going to other countries but it could be from other countries.
Curve paths may lie in different part of the earth, for example, from Australia (which is at the bottom part of the earth) going to other countries.

Is there anything I can do to always keep my airplane upright as it is moving along the curve path?

Comment: I'm not sure this solves your problem but the following fiddle shows how you can animate an object on a sphere with correct orientation: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/4160/. Maybe you can use parts of it to solve your problem. I've also use `TWEEN.js` for animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to use .lookAt() before but it doesn't work. I will try to work with .setFromSpherical().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now by using Frenet–Serret formulas (TNB Frame).
I used Tangent, Normal, and Binormal to create a matrix (Matrix4) then used that matrix to set the rotation of planes by using .setRotationFromMatrix().

This is now the code to animate the planes:

```
function animatePlane(plane, line, key) {

        if (key > 1) {
            key = 1;
        } else {
            key = Math.round(key * 100) / 100;
        }

        var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(line.vertices), matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        var duration = 300, position = curve.getPointAt(key);

        if ((key > 0) && (key < 1)) {

            var D = curve.getPointAt(1).normalize(), X = plane.position.clone().normalize();
            var T = position.clone().normalize(), B = curve.getTangentAt(key), N = new THREE.Vector3();

            N.crossVectors(D, T).normalize();

            matrix.set(
                N.x, B.x, T.x, X.x,
                N.y, B.y, T.y, X.y,
                N.z, B.z, T.z, X.z,
                0, 0, 0, 1
            );

            plane.setRotationFromMatrix(matrix);
        }   

        new TWEEN.Tween(plane.position)
            .to({ x: position.x, y: position.y, z: position.z }, duration)
            .onUpdate(function() {
                plane.position.set(this.x, this.y, this.z);
            })
            .onComplete(function() {

                if (key < 1) {
                    key += 0.02;
                } else {
                    key = 0;
                }

                animatePlane(plane, line, key);
            })
            .start();
    }
```

and added this to make the plane above the curve path:

```
var plane1 = createPlane('airplane.png');

plane1.renderOrder = 1;
plane1.onBeforeRender = function(renderer) {
    renderer.clearDepth(); 
}

animatePlane(plane1, line1, 0);
```